# How to access option from dropdown menu in VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am new to VBA and i have to select option 2 from a dropdown menu in one of the internet explorer pages of a specific website.

Here is a snapshot of the html code of the webpage. 
[image]

I cannot figure out a way of accessing the dropdown option in VBA. 
I tried using this but ist doesn't seem to target the element i want.

```
Set objShell3 = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
              IE_count = objShell3.Windows.Count
              For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            my_url = objShell3.Windows(x).document.Location
            my_title = objShell3.Windows(x).document.Title
             MsgBox ("The title of this page is: " & my_title)


         If my_title Like "Export to Excel" & "*" Then
        Set ie3 = objShell3.Windows(x).document
        my_title3 = ie3.Title
        MsgBox ("The title of Export to Excel is: " & my_title3)
        Exit For
    Else
End If

Next

      For Each element In ie3.getElementsByTagName("a")
  If element.innerText = "Option2" Then

    element.Click
      Exit For
        Else
    End If
Next
```

Is there any specific syntax to access the options of a dropdown menu in vba?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share the url or paste the html using the snippet tool via [edit] so we can copy paste for testing

Comment: From the picture of your HTML code it looks like what you are trying to select is a span tag which does not has any event. If you post your sample HTML than we can try to run it and check its structure. Than we can make a test with the VBA code may help to get idea about how to accomplish your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A url would be helpful indeed but what you are looking for must be in that select tag element.

HTML name attributes are not always unique but assuming that's the first one with this name you can set the select element into an object this way:

```
Set objSelect = ie3.getElementsByName("selectedHostId")(0)
```

If you expand that element, you'll see that it has child elements with option tag. 
Option tags have value and also innertext which are not always the same. You have to use the value.

```
objSelect.Value = "ValeOfOptionElementYouNeed"
```

The dropdown has an onChange event. You might need to "fire" it in order to imitate a manual selection:

```
objSelect.FireEvent "onChange"
```